# Внедрение информации о типах в .NET из C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

У меня есть native c++ dll, есть с++/cli враппер для нее (назовем эту длл-ку adaptor.dll).
Также есть С# dll которая использует враппер. Эта длл-ка распространяемая (назовем ее assembly.dll).

Чтобы конечный пользователь мог использовать assembly.dll в своем проекте, необходимо чтобы он добавил в референсы обе длл-ки - assembly и adaptor. Чего собственно хотелось бы избежать.

Происходит это потому, что в adaptor.dll есть свои типы которые возвращаются либо принимаются как параметры. Соот-но если добавить только assembly.dll то будут ошибки, так как типы неизвестны.

Как избежать добавления референса в проект для adaptor.dll. Можно ли как то смерджить только информацию о типах? Идея с написанием классов оберток не подходит по ТЗ. ILMerge также не подходит, так как у меня две версии adaptor.dll - для х86 и х64 и всё это должно работать с AnyCPU (сейчас я загружаю нужную версию используя AssemblyResolve обработчик).

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну значит нужно пересогласовывать ТЗ. Чтобы использовать тип в сигнатурах методов, нужно иметь статическую зависимость на сборку, в которой он определен, так устроена платформа. Иное невозможно и бессмысленно.